# Assign value for multiple input boxes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi I have a problem in assign single values to multiple input boxes. i am trying many ways but it assign only 1 text box. How can I assign multiple text boxes.

Note: I have the same ID for all input boxes.

My code is given below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInputs()
{
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var ids = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
  {
    if(inputs[i].getAttribute('id').toLowerCase()== 'myid')
    {       
       document.getElementsById('myid').value="1";
    }
  }   
}    
window.onload = getInputs;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text"  id="myid"><br>
  <input type="text"  id="myid"><br>
  <input type="text"  id="myid"><br>
  <input type="text"  id="myid"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It only assigns a value to one of because ID's should be unique; therefore you're only actually going to end up targetting the first one with that value assignment.

Change your HTML to use a class instead:

```
<input type="text"  class="myids"><br>
<input type="text"  class="myids"><br>
<input type="text"  class="myids"><br>
<input type="text"  class="myids"><br>
```

Then, you can adapt your JavaScript accordingly.

---

**jQuery**

in jQuery, you could then set a value using:

`$('.myids').val('value for all of them here');`

[**jQuery jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TChpx/)

---

**Pure JavaScript**

In Javascript, you'd use `getElementsByClassName()` and iterate through them, giving them the same value.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('myids');
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].value = "New!";
}
```

**[Pure JavaScript jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/TChpx/1/)**

Answer (score 4):

The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique so having the same `id` several times is **invalid html** and most browsers will simply ignore any inputs with `id`s that already exist int he dom tree.

Sidenote: To set the value of several ids (via jquery) use the `val()` function and a selector that selects all respective inputs like this (it looks alot more cleaner to have this in a one-liner as opposed to sticking to pure javascript):

```
$('#myid1, #myid2, .myclass1').val('new value');
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all ids are supposed to be unique. So add a `class` or `name` attribute instead. But your main problem is here:

```
document.getElementsById('myid').value="1";
```

It should be

```
inputs[i].value="1";
```

You already have the element, there is no need to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

Put your input boxes in a div container with an ID or Class. Then use the following code.

```
$('#divID').find('input:text').val('your value');
```

or

```
$('.divClass').find('input:text').val('your value');
```

The first one is used for if you are using ID for the div and the second one is for the class as the selector. This code will find you all input text boxes in that particular div container and assign your value to them.