# How can I display current date in multiple text boxes within the same DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, the code I'm using only works with one text box because of the element ID. I tried to duplicate the script with different IDs for different text boxes, only 1 text box would show.

```
<script>
  var todaydate = new Date();
  var day = todaydate.getDate();
  var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
  var datestring = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
  window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("date").value = datestring;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="date"/ >
```

Comment: If you duplicate with different ids, you have to repeat the line that sets the value for each id.  If you use a shared class, you have to loop over all of them and set each of their value.

Comment: But related to "I tried ... only 1 ... would show", please show us what you tried that did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign value for multiple input boxes using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355959/assign-value-for-multiple-input-boxes-using-javascript)

Comment: Quicķest: Put more input fields in the body (with ids) and copy the line 'document.getElementById("date2").value...' with the right id. Also place the script below the html so the script can find the elements...  or look at loops and load sequences in js like answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that ?

```js
var datestring  = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

// initialize Date to any element  with specific ID
document.querySelectorAll('#date1, #date2, #date3, #date4')
        .forEach(item => item.value = datestring )
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date1" ><br>
<input type="text" id="date2" ><br>
<input type="text" id="date3" ><br>
<input type="text" id="date4" ><br>
```

But it is more easy if they use a same class:

```js
var datestring  = new Date().toLocaleDateString();


// initialize Date to any element input with class="inDate"
document.querySelectorAll('input.inDate')
        .forEach( item => item.value = datestring )
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date1" class="inDate" ><br>
<input type="text" id="date2" class="inDate" ><br>
<input type="text" id="date3" class="inDate" ><br>
<input type="text" id="date4" class="inDate" ><br>
```